# 特定のルートのみReact(JavaScript)からLumen(PHP)へAjaxをした際にCORSで弾かれる。

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, reactjs, axios

### 概要

現在下記の様な構成のアプリケーションを開発しています。

[image: 構成図]

フロントエンドにReact.js、バックエンドにAPIサーバーのLumen、その間にリバースプロキシとしてNginxを置いています。
そこで、ReactからPromiseベースのAjaxライブラリであるaxiosを使ったところCORSで弾かれました。
Lumen側でCORSの設定をし、一応は回避することはできたのですが、特定のページにいくとまたCORSで弾かれます。
画面の遷移にはreact-routerを使用しています。個人的にはwebpack、もしくはnginxの設定が間違っていると考えています。
自分なりに色々調べてみましたが、解決せず…。
どなたか解決方法のご教授お願いいたします。

### エラーの内容

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/sticky' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

### 該当のコード

```
// nginx

server {
    listen       0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    charset      utf-8;

    # Root
    location / {
        root    /var/www/client/dist;
        index   index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin');
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
          add_header 'Vary: Origin');
        }

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
    }

    # ReverseProxy: Lumen API server
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass  server:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include       fastcgi_params;
        }

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin');
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
          add_header 'Vary: Origin');
        }

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
    }
}
```

```
// Lumen

<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // TODO:Access-Control-Allow-Originを適切に指定する必要がある
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        ];

        // preflightリクエスト用
        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

```
// webpack.config.js

import path from 'path'

const src = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
const dist = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: ['@babel/polyfill', src + '/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: dist,
        filename: "main.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                // css
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: {
                    include: /node_modules/,
                    // quill.js
                    exclude: /node_modules\/react-quill\//
                },
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            url: false,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                // js
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false }]]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                // tsx
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
            },
            {
                // image
                test: /\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|png|PING|gif|mp3|svg|ttf|woff2|woff|eot)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                        name: "[name].[ext]",
                        outputPath: "assets/img",
                        publicPath: path => "/assets/img/" + path
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 3000,
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
};
```

### バージョン

Lumen 6.3.3

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/246761

Comment: nginx の　"add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');" て　Access-Control-Allow-Methodsでは？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！terateilの方でも指摘され、色々試してみましたが、ダメでしたね…。https://teratail.com/questions/246761

Answer (score -2, accepted):

PHPのエラーを修正したところ正常に動作いたしました！ありがとうございました！
原因としては、PHP 側でエラーが発生すると、CORS のヘッダーを設定する前にエラーメッセージを出力しちゃうので、ヘッダーが正常に出力されず、CORS エラーってことになる感じですかね…！CORS エラーな時点で中身（エラーメッセージも）は無視されるでしょうし。
因みにPHP側のエラーとしては存在しないクラスを使用していました。

Comment: せっかくなので、(質問の内容に対して) どのような対応を行ったのかをもう少し具体的に書いてもらうと、第三者にとっても役立つ情報になるかと思います。